# Is it possible to suspend child thread then callback parent thread and then again resume child thread

Tags: java, multithreading

*My JAVA code is creating a class that is extending thread class*

```
   public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    MyThread ct=new MyThread();
    Thread t=new Thread(ct);
    t.start();
    System.out.println(5);
    }

    public class MyThread extends Thread {
    public void run()
        {
            for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
            {  System.out.println("abc");
                if (i==5)
                    //do something


            }
```

**The output should be:-
abc
abc
abc
abc
5
abc
abc
abc
abc**

Comment: You could use [wait/notify](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html). (I suppose your parent thread does some jobs as well, otherwise a single thread would be enough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the desired output, you need not only pause the child thread when `i == 5`, but also need pause the main thread until the child thread print the first five `abc`.

You can use two [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) for communication between the child and main thread:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class Main {


    static class Child implements Runnable {

        CountDownLatch waitLatch;
        CountDownLatch notifyLatch;

        public Child(CountDownLatch waitLatch, CountDownLatch notifyLatch) {
            this.waitLatch = waitLatch;
            this.notifyLatch = notifyLatch;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                System.out.println("abc");
                if (i == 5) {
                    try {
                        notifyLatch.countDown(); // signal main thread, let it print number 5
                        waitLatch.await(); // wait for the signal from main thread
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CountDownLatch waitLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        CountDownLatch notifyLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        Runnable child = new Child(waitLatch, notifyLatch);
        new Thread(child).start();

        try {
            notifyLatch.await(); // wait for the signal from child thread
        } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {

        }
        System.out.println(5);
        waitLatch.countDown(); // resume child thread
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is simply **no** suspend/resume with Java threads (you can't even forcefully **kill** them by the way). You can't point at some arbitrary thread and instruct it to "stop doing" what it is currently doing.

Meaning: when you want such functionality, *you* have to implement it yourself. As the comment suggests, you can use [wait/notify](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) for that. Or other kind of locking mechanisms.

Other solutions would be to use a *queue* like data structure. The parent pushes "command objects" into that queue, and the child thread regularly checks the queue for new commands, and adapts itself based on the received command.

The essential point here: *your* code has to implement some sort of protocol, that allows one thread to *control* the other thread(s).

Beyond that: you have to understand that the parent thread simply **advances** on its own, after starting child threads. In your example, there is *no* sync between parent and child, therefore "5" can show up at any random point in time.